# How to delete the last element of a forward_list？

Tags: c++

I don't know how to delete the last element of the forward_list

```
forward_list<string> names {"fwfew","zhangwne","xiaobew","yaya","qiuqiu","haifeng"};
```

Comment: If you keep track of the size of the list, you can do `names.resize(--cur_size);` Note that `std::forward_list` doesn't know its own size, doesn't have `size()` member function. If you don't know the size, then you'd need to walk the list from the start until second-to-last element (which means you need two iterators marching two nodes apart) and call `erase_after` on it.

Comment: Note that deleting the last item of a forward_list is an O(N) operation, i.e. relatively expensive to perform if the length of the list isn't small.  If it's something you think you'll need to do often, you might consider switching to a `std::list` or `std::vector` or etc instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you simply don't do that. If erasing the last element is an operation that you need to do, then it's likely that a forward list isn't the appropriate container for the use case.

That said, you can use linear search to find second to last iterator and use `erase_after`. In the case only one element exists, use `pop_front` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove the last element of the singly link list which is implemented as std::forward_list . It's obvious you can't do that without doing the second  Last element of the list .

If you want to do this then there are many work arounds to iterate to second last and calling erase after .

and if you know how many elementa are there then ,

```
forward_list<string> names {"fwfew","zhangwne","xiaobew","yaya","qiuqiu","haifeng"};

auto next_val = std::next( names.begin(), 4 );
 
names.erase_after( next_val );
```